# How to change loop with SELECT in abap to field-symbol

Tags: abap, opensql

I have a code like this:

```
i_mahn is a itab.
Data: gt_mahn type table of i_mahn,
gs_result type i_mahn.
  LOOP AT gt_mahn into gs_result
    SELECT * FROM mhnd
                 INTO gs_mhnd
                 WHERE laufd EQ gs_result-laufd
                 AND   laufi EQ gs_result-laufi
                 AND   cpdky EQ gs_result-cpdky
      MOVE-CORRESPONDING gs_mhnd TO gs_result.
    ENDSELECT.
  ENDLOOP.
```

and I want to change it to a loop with a field symbol but how? I know that the field-symbol only contains the positions of where the information have been but I dont know how to use the field symbol withe the select in this case....

```
field-symbols: <gs_mahn> like line of gt_mahn
  LOOP AT gt_mahn appending <gs_mahn>
    SELECT * FROM mhnd
                 INTO ???
                 WHERE laufd EQ <gs_mahn>-laufd
                 AND   laufi EQ <gs_mahn>-laufi
                 AND   cpdky EQ <gs_mahn>-cpdky
      MOVE-CORRESPONDING ??? TO ???.
    ENDSELECT.
  ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You use of field-symbols here is nonsensical.

Comment: Don't do SELECTs in LOOPs, it is horrible for performance. Use FOR ALL ENTRIES instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
field-symbols: <gs_mahn> like line of gt_mahn.
  LOOP AT gt_mahn ASSIGNING <gs_mahn>.
    SELECT * FROM mhnd INTO gt_mahn
                 WHERE laufd EQ <gs_mahn>-laufd
                 AND   laufi EQ <gs_mahn>-laufi
                 AND   cpdky EQ <gs_mahn>-cpdky
      MOVE-CORRESPONDING <gs_mahn> TO <whatever>.
    ENDSELECT.
  ENDLOOP.
```

I really don't know what you are doing, but in my example you can see how to use field-symbols... google might have also known this easily ... https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenfield-symbol_inline.htm

Comment: Sry I forgot something, gt_mahn is already filled with information ans I want to use the field-symbol to add information from mhnd and display at the end it in the gs_result 

 ´ SELECT * FROM mhnk INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE gt_mahn
              WHERE bukrs EQ p_bukrs.

then select mhnd with field symbol, I cant select there into the gt_mahn because its an internal table....

Comment: then apply your changes. my solution shows how to use field symbols in a loop. StackOverflow should not be used to let others code your requirements. question solved imho.

Comment: I cant select them into my gt_mahn, so I createt a structure gs_mhnd type mhnd, can I still move from <gs_mahn> to gs_result or do I need another move to get the information from gs_mhnd to gs_result?

Comment: as I said. question is answered, this is not to solve your business problems ;-) better ask someone who knows your tables in depth.